# File data/data/com.app.myapp/files/PersistedInstallation.XXXX.json in android seems to contain an authentication token. What for?

Tags: android, security, expo

We have an Expo application using the managed workflow that we distribute for Android.
Looking at the files inside the application directory we found a json which seems to contain a specific authentication token. It seems to be created by Expo itself but we can't find anything about it on the documentation. We'd like to understand what the impact is if it is leaked and what is it used for.

File location on android:
`data/data/(com.app.myapp)/files/PersistedInstallation.(XX-some-random-ID-XX).json`

Contents:

```
{ 
"fid": "some ID different to the file",
"AuthToken": "A JWT token with 'fid', 'projectNumber', 'appId', 'exp' fields in the payload"
... (other fields for token validity)
}
```

Do you know what this file is for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of exposing auth token has been discussed in [GitHub issue #1822](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1822). I recommend reading the entire discussion from start to finish. To summarize the key points:

> "Some firebase services are accessible with these tokens. Firebase
> accounts of the developer is not." - ashwinraghav
>
> "At the moment, **it would be possible to use the installation token
> to access some firebase services**, which have **no inherent notion of
> user authentication**. I am intentionally not providing a list to keep
> things obscure for the sake of safety. **If you are worried about them
> accessing your Firebase account, there is no risk.**" - ashwinraghav